# Why can't xdebug3 access profile data in tmp folder?

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I have a php docker container in which I installed xdebug.

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
RUN  pecl install xdebug-3.0.2 > /dev/null && \
     docker-php-ext-enable xdebug > /dev/null
```

My mounted xdebug.ini (`/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`) file looks like:

```
zend_extension=xdebug

xdebug.mode=debug,profile
xdebug.client_port= 9000
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp/profile
```

and while xdebug works, I see this for the profiler files:

```
Xdebug: [Profiler] File '/tmp/profile/cachegrind.out.15' could not be opened.
```

At the end of the Dockerfile I set the user to `www-data`

```
USER www-data
```

Is that why it can't access the folder?

What does xdebug require to be able to open the file? It's within the tmp folder so I assumed it should be able to have read and write permissions there.

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug needs the directory that is instructed to write the profiler file to, to exist. If it does not exist, it can't write the file, and you will get that error message.

Xdebug's [diagnostics](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/src/lib/log.c#L190) will attempt to find out the *reason* why it can't write to a file, and will dutifully report that in it's log file (if `xdebug.log` is set to a writeable filename), as well as through the diagnostics log that it shows when you run `xdebug_info()` in the script.

In your case, you need to make sure that your Dockerfile includes:

```
RUN mkdir /tmp/profile; chmod 777 /tmp/profile
```

Alternative, you can also bind the directory if you use docker-compose, with:

```
    volumes:
      - type: "bind"
        source: "/tmp/profile"
        target: "/tmp/profile"
```

This is what I have done in Xdebug.org's [`docker-compose.yaml` file](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.org/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml).

docker-compose should create the `/tmp/profile` directory on your local system if it doesn't exist yet when starting the container(s).

Answer (score 0):

I went with adding:

```
RUN mkdir /tmp/profile; chmod 777 /tmp/profile
```

to the Dockefile.